# Транспортный слой приложения

Tags: java, android, spring, архитектура

Задумал реализовать клиент-серверное приложение на Android с применением архитектуры MVP.Также добавить транспортный слой в  приложения, который будет содержать универсальный класс для совершения запросов и выдачи данных в Model. Транспортный класс, по моей задумке, должен реализовывать следующий интерфейс:

```
interface DataTransfer<T> { 
     public T getData(String request); 
}
```

то есть, функция этого класса должна на вход получать строку запроса, и отдавать тип данных, преобразованных из JSONа. Тип получаемых данных устанавливается при создании экземпляра класса транспортного уровня. 
Собственно сабж, верны ли мои представления о транспортном слое и возможна ли реализации такого класса используя RestTemplate (если нет, то на каких библиотеках возможно)

Answer (score 1):

Посмотри в сторону [Retrofit2](http://square.github.io/retrofit/). Использую сам, крайне удобно и очень доволен. Вместе с `implementation group: 'com.squareup.retrofit2', name: 'converter-gson', version: '2.4.0'` JSON без лишнего кода преобразуется в java объекты.

Документация понятная, есть огромное количество статей и информации как с этим делом работать.

Пример с официального сайта.

```
public interface GitHubService {   
    @GET("users/{user}/repos")   
    Call<List<Repo>> listRepos(@Path("user") String user); 
}
```

P.S. В дополнение. Для MVP посмотри в сторону [Moxy](https://github.com/Arello-Mobile/Moxy). Разобраться не сложно, много информации имеется. Если ко всему прикрутить RxJava и RxAndroid и работать с Retrofit количество кода и его сложность уменьшаются в разы, увеличивается концентрация на бизнес логике. Но RxJava далась мне не просто.